# remove last comma from string statement

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, substring

I have the following statement

```
model.Activities = model.SelectedActivities.Aggregate(model.Activities, (current, activityId) => current + string.Format("({0}, {1}, {2}, null),", activityId, userId, DateTime.Now));
```

Which produces the follow:

```
(1, 1, 05/04/2015 05:09:39, null),(2, 1, 05/04/2015 05:09:39, null),(3, 1, 05/04/2015 05:09:39, null),(5, 1, 05/04/2015 05:09:39, null),(8, 1, 05/04/2015 05:09:39, null),
```

As you can see right at the end there is a comma I'm trying to remove this by doing the following:

```
var t = model.Activities.Substring(1, model.Activities.Length - 1);
```

but that statement doesn't seem to remove the last comma instead it remains the same, what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: The first parameter of `Substring` if an index.  So what you are doing here is removing the first character, not the last.  Change the first parameter to `0` instead of `1`.

Answer (score 6):

Instead of adding, and then removing the comma, it's cleaner to avoid it in the first place. This is what [`string.Join`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.String.Join(v=vs.110).aspx) is for.

First create a collection of strings to join:

```
IEnumerable<string> activities = model.SelectedActivities.Select(activityId => 
   string.Format("({0}, {1}, {2}, null),", activityId, userId, DateTime.Now));
```

And then join them together:

```
var modelActivities = string.Join(",", activities);
```

String join can receive any IEnumerable (calling ToString() on the items if they're not strings already) and join them, and is useful specifically for this very popular case of leaving the delimiter off after the last item.

**Note:** This technique *does* go over the collection twice, once to stringify, once to join. If this is a huge collection, it might be an issue. Usually, though, it won't be.

Answer (score 5):

Managed to remove it using TrimEnd(',');

```
var t = model.Activities.TrimEnd(',');
```

Answer (score 2):

It is this line that is incorrect:

```
var t = model.Activities.Substring(1, model.Activities.Length - 1);
```

Substring uses a zero based index. Changing it to this will resolve the problem:

```
var t = model.Activities.Substring(0, model.Activities.Length - 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var t = model.Activities.Remove(model.Activities.Length - 1);
```

Try this. Easy and should work.